# Set my blog as my homepage? Redirect?

Tags: redirect

When I first started my website, I had a home/landing page and I installed my blog at myurl.com/blog. I no longer need that homepage and am wondering if there is a way to set myurl.com/blog as my homepage? So if someone types in myurl.com, it will automatically go to myurl.com/blog.

I'd like to avoid any "click here to be redirected" or "you'll be redirected in 10 seconds" type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely multiple approaches, depending on your setup, but IF your setup qualifies (linux hosting etc) then a simple .htaccess permanent redirect would be the simplest approach:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /blog myurl.com
```

Comment: I don't think I have that ability with my host. I use FatCow and they have an htaccess editor that I can't figure out how to use.

Comment: Hi Julie, We are here to help, but we don't know what systems you use, what your knowledge is... how can we move forwards?